# Migrating a Magento CE 1.3 database to Magento EE 1.10 database?

Tags: mysql, migration, magento

I need to migrate a Magento 1.3 Community Edition (CE) database to a 1.10 (maybe 1.11) Magento Enterprise Edition (EE) database.

Only the database is needed. Templates, extensions etc. will be recreated from scratch.

My thoughts were to

- `mysqldump` the CE database
- create an empty EE database
- import the CE dump into the EE database using `mysql`
- install a new Magento EE 1.10 using the EE database and the CE encryption key

Would such procedure be save in terms of database consistency and operability?

Are there better approaches (best practices) to migrate the database from CE to EE?